# Express server: Error: Requested Range Not Satisfiable

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, express

Im writing my first node web server (feel free to give me feedback) that uses express and gith to deploy.  The problem is I'm receiving the below error once deploying, and if I run the script via pm2 the process seemingly gets deleted.  Any ideas?  The script is attached below.

```
sudo node server.js 
Error: Requested Range Not Satisfiable
    at SendStream.error (/home/gareth/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:145:16)
    at SendStream.send (/home/gareth/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:371:19)
    at /home/gareth/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:323:10
    at /home/gareth/node_modules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:177:31
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
Completed deployment
```

Server.js

```
/*
    Webserver
        Should use port 80 on production
        Mongo DB for database - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/
        Use pm2 to ensure it runs forever and load balanced

    NPM
        https://www.npmjs.org/package/fs
        https://www.npmjs.org/package/express
        https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser
        https://www.npmjs.org/package/gith
        https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodemailer
*/

// server monitoring
require('newrelic');

var APP = {

    // include some scripts
    express: require('express'),
    fs: require('fs'),
    mdb: require('mongodb'),
    nodemailer: require('nodemailer'),
    gith: require('gith').create(9001),
    execFile: require('child_process').execFile,

    // setup
    port: 80,
    dbUrl: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test',
    gitRepo: '*****',
    gmailUser: '*****',
    gmailPass: '******',
    email: '*****',
    subject: 'Website enquiry',
    linuxUser: '*****',
    wwwPath: '/var/www/',

    // vars
    server: null,
    app: null,
    options: {},
    smtpTransport: null,
    db: null,

    init: function (){

        // setup express
        APP.app = APP.express().use(require('body-parser')());

        // create the server
        APP.fs.exists('./ssl/privatekey.pem', function (e){
            if(e){
                APP.fs.exists('./ssl/certificate.pem', function (e){
                    if(e){
                        APP.options = {
                            key: APP.fs.readFileSync('./ssl/privatekey.pem'),
                            cert: APP.fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certificate.pem'),
                        };
                        APP.server = require('http').createServer(APP.options, APP.app).listen(APP.port, '0.0.0.0');
                    } else {
                        APP.server = require('http').createServer(APP.app).listen(APP.port, '0.0.0.0');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                APP.server = require('http').createServer(APP.app).listen(APP.port, '0.0.0.0');
            }
        });

        // set up smtp
        APP.smtpTransport = APP.nodemailer.createTransport('Gmail',{
            auth: {
                user: APP.gmailUser,
                pass: APP.gmailPass,
            }
        });

        // http routing
        APP.routing();

        // wait for github push
        APP.gith({
            repo: APP.gitRepo
        }).on('all', function(payload){
            if(payload.branch === 'master' && payload.original.commits[0].message.indexOf('#deploy') >= 0){

                APP.execFile('/home/'+APP.linuxUser+'/deploy.sh', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                    console.log('Completed deployment');
                });

            }
        });

    },

    // open the db
    openDB: function (){

        APP.mdb.connect(APP.dbURL, function(err, db){

            if(err)
                throw err;

            APP.db = db;

        });

    },

    // close the db
    closeDB: function (){

        APP.db.close();

    },

    // insert a file to the db
    create: function (col, data){

        // open the db
        APP.openDB();

        var collection = APP.db.collection(col);
        collection.insert(data, function(err, docs){
            if(err){
                console.warn(err.message);
            } else {
                console.log('Successfully inserted record');
            }
        });

        // close the db
        APP.closeDB();

    },

    // insert a file to the db
    update: function (col, crit, data){

        // open the db
        APP.openDB();

        // example criteria
        // {key: value} // get something specific
        // {key: {$lt: value}} // Less Than
        // {key: {$gte: value}} // Greater than or equal to
        // {key: {$ne: 'value'}} // Not Equal To
        // {key: {$in: ['value', 'value', 'value']}} // Exists in array

        // updateoperators
        //   db.col.update({key: 'value'}, {$addToSet: {key: ['value']}});
        // Or we can add a new field to Cash
        //   db.col.update({key: 'value'}, {$set: {'age': 50} });
        // You can also push and pull items from arrays:
        //   db.col.update({key: 'value'}, {$push: {'key': 'value'} });
        //   db.col.update({key: 'value'}, {$pull: {'key': 'value'} });

        var collection = APP.db.collection(col);
        collection.update(crit, data, function (){
            if(err){
                console.warn(err.message);
            } else {
                console.log('Successfully updated record');
            }
        });

        // close the db
        APP.closeDB();

    },

    // find all in the db collection that match
    read: function (col, crit){

        // open the db
        APP.openDB();

        // example criteria
        // {key: value} // get something specific
        // {key: {$lt: 5}} // Less Than
        // {key: {$gte: 10}} // Greater than or equal to
        // {key: {$ne: 'b'}} // Not Equal To
        // {key: {$in: ['a', 'b', 'c']}} // Exists in array

        var collection = APP.db.collection(col);
        collection.find(crit).toArray(function(err, results) {
            if(err){
                console.warn(err.message);
            } else {
                console.log(results);
            }
        });

        // close the db
        APP.closeDB();

    },

    // find and delete from collection
    delete: function (col, crit){

        // open the db
        APP.openDB();

        // example criteria
        // {key: value} // get something specific
        // {key: {$lt: 5}} // Less Than
        // {key: {$gte: 10}} // Greater than or equal to
        // {key: {$ne: 'b'}} // Not Equal To
        // {key: {$in: ['a', 'b', 'c']}} // Exists in array

        var collection = APP.db.collection(col);
        collection.remove(crit);

        // close the db
        APP.closeDB();

    },

    // routing files
    routing: function (){

        // hide the engine creating the server
        APP.app.disable('x-powered-by');

        // index page
        APP.app.get('/*', function (req, res, next){
            APP.renderPage(req, res, next);
        });

        // handle post data
        APP.app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
            APP.sendEmail(req);
            APP.renderPage(req, res, next);
        });

        APP.app.post('/index.html', function(req, res, next) {
            APP.sendEmail(req);
            APP.renderPage(req, res, next);
        });

    },

    // render page
    renderPage: function (req, res, next){

        // get the host and point to correct folder
        var host = req.get('host');
        if(host.indexOf('www.') >= 0){
            host = host.replace('www.', '');
        }

        // see if we are on staging
        if(host.indexOf('staging.') >= 0){

            // tidy url
            host = host.replace('staging.', '');

            var url = APP.wwwPath + host + '/app';
            APP.fs.exists(url + req.url, function (e){
                if(e){
                    res.sendfile(url + req.url);
                } else {
                    res.sendfile(url + '/404.html');
                }
            });

        } else {

            var url = APP.wwwPath + host + '/dist';
            APP.fs.exists(url + req.url, function (e){
                if(e){
                    res.sendfile(url + req.url);
                } else {
                    res.sendfile(url + '/404.html');
                }
            });

        }

    },

    // sanitize post
    sendEmail: function (req){

        var name = req.body.name,
        email = req.body.email,
        msg = req.body.msg,
        nameRegex = /^([ \u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'\-])+$/,
        emailRegex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\']+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\']+)*)|(\'.+\'))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

        if(emailRegex.test(email) && nameRegex.test(name) && msg.length > 10){

            // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
            var mailOptions = {
                from: name + ' <' + email + '>',
                to: APP.email,
                subject: APP.subject,
                text: msg,
                html: '<p>'+ msg +'</p>'
            }

            // send mail with defined transport object
            APP.smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }else{
                    console.log('Message sent: ' + response.message);
                }

                // shut down the connection pool - no more messages
                //smtpTransport.close();
            });

        }

    }

};

// run the script
APP.init();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what occurred but it works when I break the two server instance or functions out of the same file.  I now have two files/server instances working on different ports on the server

Comment: I have a simple Express app crashing on this error.

Comment: Can you post the source to github or somewhere? I would like the full source to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you use `require('https')`?
Also investigate `express.static`...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the error is coming out of your deploy.sh script.

To fix this, make sure that outgoing requests do not have the `Content-Range`.

Also might help to post the deploy.sh

Answer (score 0):

Try passing acceptRanges: false as an argument to the res.sendFile method.

So instead of calling `res.sendFile(filePath)`
use `res.sendFile(filePath, {acceptRanges: false})`

Answer (score 0):

This is an error raised when browser (client) tries to download a file many time. like when trying to download the file in smaller chunks. (For example when the browser tries to download a video file, part by part, to buffer and display it for user, and as the user watches it, the browser would download more parts of the video).

To see how browser is using your URL to download the file just put a counter and print it in console and you will see how many times it is being called.

To solve this you have to disable `Content-Range`. For example use `res.sendFile(filePath, {acceptRanges: false})`